# ExtendVirtualDisk_Task, vSphere web services SDK

Tags: c#, vsphere

I want to extend the size of a virtual disk file automatically, but I'm running into an Exception. My system is running vCenter 4 and vSphere 4.
I don't know if the following code is correct. Any solution?

```
public bool ExpandDiskSize(string vmname, int diskNumber, int diskSize)
        {
            NameValueCollection filter = new NameValueCollection();
            filter.Add("Summary.vm", vmname);
            VMware.Vim.VirtualMachine vm = (VMware.Vim.VirtualMachine)client.FindEntityView(typeof(VMware.Vim.VirtualMachine), null, filter, null);
            try
            {
                NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
                nvc.Add("name", "Datacenter");
                VMware.Vim.Datacenter dc = (VMware.Vim.Datacenter)client.FindEntityView(typeof(VMware.Vim.Datacenter), null, nvc, null);
                VirtualDiskManager vdm = new VirtualDiskManager(client,  new ManagedObjectReference());
                vdm.ExtendVirtualDisk_Task(vm.Layout.Disk[diskNumber].DiskFile[0].ToString(), dc.MoRef, diskSize *1024 * 1024, false);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                Logger.Instance.WriteLog(LoggingLevel.ERROR, ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: ExtendVirtualDisk_Task is marked as experimental for vSphere4: http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk41pubs/ApiReference/index.html. In my experience that often means, it doesn't work at all. Do you have the same problem when using vSphere5?